# Доступ к документу во фрейме. Frontend Test Automation

Tags: юнит-тесты, ui, test-automation, playwright

### В тест-кейсе нужно заполнить **input[id="card"]**, который находится внутри iframe. Необходимо воспользоваться Playwright.

В [**документации Playwright**](https://playwright.dev/docs/frames) есть метод **frame()**, который возвращает iframe, соответствующий указанным критериям. Необходимо передать 1 параметр: ***значение атрибута name*** или ***URL-адрес***.

Решение должно быть простым:

```
const myFrame = page.frame('element382');
await myFrame?.locator('input[id="card"]').fill('0123456789');
```

Но, при каждом обновлении страницы моё **значение атрибута name** и **мой url-адрес** динамически изменяются - *число 382 заменяется на другое.*

(P.S. ссылка src выдумана, но смысл в том, что **значение id** или **name** находится в ссылке)

```
<iframe id="element382" name="element382" src="https://something/link/&element382">
...
  <input id="card">
...
</iframe>
```